# print scrollable vb.net form

Tags: vb.net

I have tried PRINTFORM, PRINTDOCUMENT from visual studio power packs but then also i am not able to print the complete scrollable form.
I am using visual studio 2010.

Can anyone help me?
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set [PrintForm.PrintOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.printform.printoption%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
PrintForm1.Print(Me, Scrollable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Visual Basic PowerPacks.
Set the `PrintAction` property to `PrintToPrinter`.

```
PrintForm1.Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.Scrollable)
```